# getting issue while working with nested routes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, rendering, nested-routes

I am getting issues while rendering contact data.

Here the case is when I click the continue button in my app it triggers the `checkoutContinuedHandler()` function that results in a change of URL but the `ContactData` component is not rendered and my `CheckoutSummary` component also vanishes as I am rendering it on the same page.

I Checked twice that export is done and there is no spelling mistakes.
I tried different solutions from the stack and discussed them with my mate still the issue is on...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import CheckoutSummary from "../../components/Order/CheckoutSummary/CheckoutSummary";
import ContactData from "./ContactData/ContactData";

class Checkout extends Component {
  state = {
    ingredients: {
      salad: 1,
      meat: 1,
      cheese: 1,
      bacon: 1,
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const ingredients = {};
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
      // ['salad','1']
      ingredients[param[0]] = +param[1];
    }
    this.setState({ ingredients: ingredients });
  }

  checkoutCancelledHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  };

  checkoutContinuedHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.replace("/checkout/contact-data");
    console.log(this);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CheckoutSummary
          ingredients={this.state.ingredients}
          checkoutCancelled={this.checkoutCancelledHandler}
          checkoutContinued={this.checkoutContinuedHandler}
        />
        <Route
          path={this.props.match.path + "/contact-data"}
          component={ContactData}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: You mention that you tried different solutions that did not work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried wrapping the export with withRouter.

Comment: And what happened? Was there an error?

Comment: No, as soon as I click the continue button the screen goes blank.. though the URL is updated